# Не работает копирование timestamp

Tags: yii2

MySQL 5.7.25
Есть поле `'created_date' TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`
rules для полей дат:

```
[['created_date', 'root_created_date'], 'safe'],
```

При создании записи значение поля `created_date` заполняется по умолчанию. Я хочу создать копию записи в базе. Для этого делаю следующее:

```
$root = $this->createRoot();
```

Который вызывает:

```
public function createRoot()
{
  $root = new Entry();
  ------
  $root->created_date = $this->created_date;
  $root->root_created_date = new \yii\db\Expression('CURTIME(6)');
  return $root->save() ? $root : null;
}
```

Проблема в том, что строчка `$root->created_date = $this->created_date;` не выполняется. Сама копия записи создается. Но значение created_date заполняется NULL.

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($this->created_date)`  и там у Вас будет `null`

Comment: Вы правы, почему-то null. Понадеялся на базу, что она сама выставит `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`. И этого она не делала. Пришлось явно указывать в коде через `new \yii\db\Expression('CURTIME(6)')` для оригинальной записи. Я запускал копирование по условиям сразу же после создания оригинала. Предполагаю, что база не успевала выставить  время создания записи по умолчанию, потому что если копирование не запускалось, в базе выставлялось время по умолчанию для оригинала. Или я, наверное, не совсем понимаю как это работает?

Comment: `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` выставить БД при сохранении, но в текущем объекте, скорее всего, этого времени не будет.